# unable to Generate a ZIP file on the fly and send it to the user’s browser for download

Tags: java, grails, response, zip, savefiledialog

I have URLs of Audio Clips. I want to download all those clips from their's URLs and want to put all these clips in single zip file. If I specify the hard coded path in code, I am able to successfully download that on specified location in zip form with all clips. But, I want to generate pop-up window prompting user to specify the path to download that zip file.
Here is my code:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  ZipOutputStream zipFile = new ZipOutputStream(baos)

  for (int i = 0; i < clipsCount; i++) {            

        String fileName = getSessionId() + ".mp4";

        try {

            //Opening Connection to the Downloading Link
            URLConnection conn = new URL(sessionToDownload.getConvertedLinkURL()).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);

            //Adding File in the Zipped Resource
            def file1Entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            zipFile.putNextEntry(file1Entry);

            //Getting Required File
            zipFile << conn.getInputStream();

            //Closing Current Zip Entry
            zipFile.closeEntry();

            println "Session to Download: " + listofId.getAt(i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            println "Exception while Downloading Session: "+ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    zipFile.close()
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"/download.zip\" ")
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.outputStream << baos
    response.outputStream.flush()
    webRequest.renderView = false;
```

So, here in Loop it iterates for each clip, download it and make it part of zip file.

Kindly, guide me if I am doing anything wrong or I can achieve this by some other way.
Thanks for you time, consideration and guidance.

Comment: are you saving all your files using the same filename?

Comment: No, each file in that zip file has different names

Comment: your code states the opposite. you name all zipEntries using the same `fileName` variable

Comment: If you see carefully I am changing the 'fileName' variable in each iteration of the loop

Comment: if `getSessionId()` does what I think it does, it should have the very same value not only for the whole loop, but also for the whole session :)

Comment: also, it's not clear, why `sessionToDownload.getConvertedLinkURL()` should change for each iteration, as it's neither parametrized with `i` nor using any `iterator`

Comment: Okay lemme make you clear things in details.
1. fileName will be different for each file
2. sessionToDownload.getConvertedLinkURL() will return the URL of the file that I will firstly download and then it will become the part of that zip file

Answer (score 0):

Your action should work actually. 
The browser `Save as..` dialog automatically opens, if it sees `"Content-disposition"`-header with `"attachment; filename=aaa.zip"` as a value in the response.

Try removing the quotes:

```
response.setHeader 'Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=download.zip'
```

Comment: and what are you seeing in the browser/log? if you dump the `baos` to disk, is it a valid zip-file?

Comment: It doesn't generate Zip files at all

Answer (score 0):

I have Investigated this Issue actually it was produced due to issue described here:
[Sending Multiple Selected Items from Controller to View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931996/sending-multiple-selected-items-from-controller-to-view)

There was one more issue that was not allowing it to appear at browser end. Here is what worked for me:

```
    //Setting Response Required Parameters
    response.setContentType('APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM')
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="example.zip"')

     InputStream contentStream = null;
    ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(response.outputStream);

    for (int i = 0; i < listofId.length; i++) {

        def sessionToDownload = Sessions.get(listofId.getAt(i));

        if (sessionsToDownload != null) {

            String fileName = sessionToDownload.getSessionId() + ".mp4";

            try {

                //Opening Connection to the Downloading Link
                URLConnection conn = new URL(sessionToDownload.getConvertedLinkURL()).openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);

                //Getting file contents
                contentStream = conn.getInputStream();

                //Adding File in the Zipped Resource
                def file1Entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
                zip.putNextEntry(file1Entry);
                zip.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(contentStream));

                println "Session to Download: " + fileName;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                println "Exception while Downloading Session: " + ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    zip.close();
}
```